# How map works over (string,arrayList) using js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vonage

I am using Nexmo to make a call which generates three uuids for single call. The uuids are generated at different times so I store them in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as (string, arraylist). Since I am making multiple calls, I need to check which call to hang up. How can I retrieve the key(string) of the map in Node.js? I've attached the API code below:

```
app.post('/events', function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
var baseURL = req.headers.host;
var from = req.body.from;

console.log("req.body.from", req.body.from)

if (req.body.status == "answered" ) {
    //uuid's generated at different timings.and these uuid's are pushed into conversationIDs arrays.
    conversationIDs.push(req.body.uuid);

} else if (req.body.status == "completed") {
  // I should not add the conversation id arraylist over here but i dont have anyother options left. 
   map.set(req.body.conversation_uuid,conversationIDs);

    var jwt = nexmo.generateJwt();

    async.forEach(conversationIDs, function (id, calbk) {
        request({
            url: 'https://api-us-1.nexmo.com/v1/calls/' + req.body.conversation_uuid,//understood that i should not delete using conversation id. But dnt know how to proceed further.
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt,
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "action": "hangup"
            })
        }, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Err', err)
                // res.end()
                calbk()
            } else {
                console.log("success");
                // res.end()
                calbk()
            }
        })
        })
    }


res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: `map.keys` or `map.entries`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) which returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) to get both the `conversation_uuid` and `conversationIDs`. However, if you're only concerned with the `conversation_uuid` (the key), you can use [`map.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys).

Let's take a look at the sample map below:

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('050160e7-4d20-4ffd-97d3-7430a3d2e8db', ['conversationId1', 'conversationId2']);
map.set('111360e7-4d20-4ffd-97d3-7430a3d2e8db', ['conversationId3', 'conversationId4']);
```

As you can see above, we've created a map and set two entries. To retrieve the first key(`conversation_uuid`), you can do the following:

```
var iterator = map.keys();
var firstConversationUuid = iterator.next().value;
console.log(firstConversationUuid);
> "050160e7-4d20-4ffd-97d3-7430a3d2e8db"
```

Keep in mind that you would have to keep iterating over each item to get all of the keys.

The same methodology can be applied to `map.entries`, but instead the `iterator.next().value` would return an array with both the key and the value.

```
var entriesIterator = map.entries();
var item1 = entriesIterator.next().value;
console.log(item1);
> Array ["050160e7-4d20-4ffd-97d3-7430a3d2e8db", Array ["conversationId1", "conversationId2"]]
```

Comment: The actual issue is the values that I add in the ArrayList gets generated dynamically. If I make multiple calls the uuid's gets generated simultaneously and i couldn't differentiate between them as I add it in ArrayList.